# Asp.net button (nothing happen)

Tags: asp.net, class

I am using the visual studio, I try to add button and then double click on it, but nothing happens (it's not going to the code behind), also it's not the same design with originally.

My another question: ( code behind)

When I click the send button, I want to show all my collected data at an empty page.

```
<fieldset>

    <div class="legend"><h3>iletisim</h3></div>

    <div class="form_row">

        <div class="form_property form_required">Adiniz</div>
        <div class="form_value"> <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txbadiniz"/>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="txbadiniz" ErrorMessage="Bos birakilamaz">
                </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>

        <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>

    <div class="form_row">

        <div class="form_property">Email</div>
        <div class="form_value"> <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txbemail"/>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="txbemail" ErrorMessage="Bos birakilamaz" 
                ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>

        <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>

    <div class="form_row">

        <div class="form_property">Telefon</div>
        <div class="form_value"> <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="txbtelefon"/>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="txbtelefon" ErrorMessage="Bos birakilamaz" 
                ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>

        <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>

    <div class="form_row">

        <div class="form_property form_required">Mesaj</div>
        <div class="form_value"><textarea rows="10" name="comment"></textarea></div>

        <div class="clearer">&nbsp;</div>

    </div>

    <div class="form_row form_row_submit">

        <div class="form_value">

        <asp:Button ID="Btngonder" runat="server" Text="Gonder" /></div>
        <div class="clearer"></div>

    </div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Will you please make your second part of the question more clear?

Comment: when i made the click on submit button, i want to see the all datas which is entered texboxes , i want to see all in at another empty page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach an event handler to the Button's OnClick event.

```
<asp:Button ID="Btngonder" runat="server" Text="Gonder" OnClick="Btngonder_Click" />
```

And in the code-behind, an event handler...

```
protected void Btngonder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // do something useful here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the debugger is not running.  Sometimes visual studio will not let you change the code while the debugger is active.

Answer (score 0):

On the ASPX page, in the asp:Button definition, add OnClick="", i.e., whatever you want to call the procedure. Then in the code-behind define

```
protected void MyProcedure(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
<put your code here>
}
```

Comment: i add the onclick but still nothing happen when i double click on its.

Comment: ...and have you added the code-behind handler and recompiled?

Comment: yes, usually when i made a button. then i double click on its at design page , then its goes to code behind page, but now its not gone anywhere :)

Comment: I don't know why it's not taking you to the code behind, but you can just add the procedure manually as described above. Also make sure you're not debug mode, as mistercain suggests.